# Mysql query with multiple left joins from tables that are subsets of the "from" table not working as expected

Tags: mysql, left-join

Making a database for inbound calls with data for each type of call.  I've defined a database with a "records" table, a "sales" table, and an "accounts_receivable" table.  The "sales" and "accounts_receivable" tables are essentially subsets of the "records" table.  Meaning, there is a corresponding row in the "records" table for each row of both the "sales" and "accounts_receivable" tables (exclusively).

My "records" table has values:

```
id (BIGINT)
timestamp (TIMESTAMP)
rep_id (INT)
notes (VARCHAR)
```

My "sales" table has values:

```
local_record_id (BIGINT)
record_id (BIGINT)
amount (VARCHAR)
bottles_sold (VARCHAR)
record_type (VARCHAR) default 'sales'
```

My "accounts_receivable" table has values:

```
local_record_id (BIGINT)
record_id (BIGINT)
amount (VARCHAR)
bottles_sold (VARCHAR)
record_type (VARCHAR) default 'ar'
```

I'm trying to pull all of the records in the entire database with the applicable data for each record.  To do this, I thought a LEFT JOIN starting with the "records" table would work just fine, but for some reason it's not.  This is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM $table_name_records
LEFT JOIN $table_name_sales ON ($table_name_records.id = $table_name_sales.record_id)
LEFT JOIN $table_name_ar ON ($table_name_records.id = $table_name_ar.record_id)
```

This is returning a set of results where the data from the subset tables with similar column names are getting blanked out.

Example of output (which corresponds to an row/entry in the "sales" table of my database):

```
Array (
    [id] => 1
    [timestamp] => 2014-12-17 13:11:07
    [rep_id] => 37
    [notes] => Some notes for you.
    [local_record_id] =>
    [record_id] =>
    [amount] =>
    [bottles_sold] =>
    [record_type] =>
)
```

I've verified that there is data in each of the columns of each of the subset tables of my database, so I don't understand why the values are coming back as blank.  If I query with only a single left join:

```
SELECT *
FROM $table_name_records
LEFT JOIN $table_name_sales ON ($table_name_records.id = $table_name_sales.record_id)
```

I get what I expect to see:

```
Array (
    [id] => 1
    [timestamp] => 2014-12-17 13:11:07
    [rep_id] => 37
    [notes] => Some notes for you.
    [local_record_id] => 14
    [record_id] => 1
    [amount] => 45.45
    [bottles_sold] => Multiple
    [record_type] => sales
)
```

Works the same way as I expect if I left join only the "accounts-receivable" table:

```
SELECT *
FROM $table_name_records
LEFT JOIN $table_name_ar ON ($table_name_records.id = $table_name_ar.record_id)

Array (
    [id] => 1
    [timestamp] => 2014-12-17 13:12:16
    [rep_id] => 37
    [notes] => Some notes.
    [local_record_id] => 6
    [record_id] => 2
    [amount] => 50.89
    [bottles_sold] => Single
    [record_type] => ar
)
```

I've reviewed the awesome graphical SQL join doc [MySQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg), and the LEFT JOIN there looks like exactly what I want: every thing from Table A (records) with the data from Table B (sales) and then also from a second Table B (accounts_receivable) attached to the appropriate rows (per the ON statement).

What am I doing wrong that this isn't responding as I'm expecting it to?

My queries where I only want "sales" records are typically structured in the other direction.  Thus:

```
SELECT *
FROM $table_name_sales
LEFT JOIN $table_name_records ON ($table_name_records.id = $table_name_sales.record_id)
```

So, I tried structuring my query from that direction and then just joining them via:

```
SELECT *
FROM $table_name_sales
LEFT JOIN $table_name_records ON ($table_name_records.id = $table_name_sales.record_id)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM $table_name_ar
LEFT JOIN $table_name_records ON ($table_name_records.id = $table_name_ar.record_id)
```

This query returns exactly what I'd expect:

```
Array (
    [id] => 1
    [timestamp] => 2014-12-17 13:11:07
    [rep_id] => 37
    [notes] => Some notes for you.
    [local_record_id] => 14
    [record_id] => 1
    [amount] => 45.45
    [bottles_sold] => Multiple
    [record_type] => sales
)
```

But it seems to me that structuring a query in this way might get expensive in the future when I have lots of records and more tables (corresponding to different types of inbound calls -- eg: information request, problem with order, etc).  I don't have a ton of experience with MySQL though.

Comment: In a `JOIN` query (any production code, really) it is _not advisable_ to `SELECT *`. As you have found, similarly named columns will not properly return.  You have to specify each (actually, only specify exactly which columns you need) and give aliases to similarly named ones:  `SELECT $table_name_records.id AS records_id, $table_name_records.notes AS records_notes, $table_accounts_receivable.bottles_sold AS ar_bottles_sold, $table_sales.bottles_sold AS sales_bottles_sold...`

Comment: Doing the `UNION` results in a very different query and result set than the `JOIN`. The JOIN seems to be what you really need here.

Comment: @MichaelB: So, I tried doing what you suggested, and I'm getting the same result.  Only this time I noticed that all of the "ar" records in the final query results look fine.  I added:  $table_name_records.id AS id,
$table_name_records.timestamp AS timestamp,
$table_name_records.rep_id AS rep_id,
$table_name_records.notes AS notes,
$table_name_sales.amount AS amount,
$table_name_sales.bottles_sold AS bottles_sold,
$table_name_sales.record_type AS record_type,
$table_name_ar.amount AS amount,
$table_name_ar.bottles_sold AS bottles_sold,
$table_name_ar.record_type AS record_type  to the query.

Comment: They all have to be _different_ aliases. You have both `$table_name_sales.bottles_sold AS bottles_sold` and `$table_name_ar.bottles_sold AS bottles_sold`.  Differentiate the aliases like `$table_name_sales.bottles_sold AS sales_bottles_sold` and `$table_name_ar.bottles_sold AS ar_bottles_sold` using a prefix for the originating table, so they both aren't `bottles_sold`. Do so for _all_ similarly named columns.

Comment: @MichaelB:  It looks like it's doing the same thing because I've aliased both of the columns from each of the subset tables to the same column in the results.  Is there a way to avoid this happening?

Comment: @MichaelB: In which case I'll need to handle each of the columns of data in similar tables separately afterward. K.  Thanks.

Comment: If you need to use sales and accounts_receivable differently, you should query them separately. Doing a JOIN with them confuses things unless the rows are truly related to each other, as opposed to just being independently related to `records`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `sales` and `accounts_receivable` tables have parallel structures, and that rows in each of those tables are related to your `records` table but not to one another.

@MichaelBerkowski pointed out the hazard of trying to interpret a resultset from `SELECT *`.

It looks to me like you need the following sort of query.

```
SELECT r.id AS record_id, r.timestamp, r.rep_id, r.notes AS record_notes,
       d.record_type, d.amount, d.bottles_sold
  FROM records AS r
  LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT record_id, record_type, amount, bottles_sold FROM sales
          UNION ALL
         SELECT record_id, record_type, amount, bottles_sold FROM accounts_receivable
       ) AS d ON d.record_id = r.id
   ORDER BY r.rep_id, r.id, r.timestamp, d.record_type DESC
```

This will present each rep's activity in order, interleaving the 'sales' and 'ar' records.

If you separately join the sales and accounts_receivable tables you'll get an unwanted combinatorial explosion. Doing UNION ALL prevents that.

Notice that you could use a single physical table for your sales and ar data.

Comment: So the actual table is much more complicated than what I presented.  I made a reduced-complexity case for the question.  I actually have 5 different subset tables, one of which has 6 sub-subset tables.  I set things up this way to save on database space because very few of the subset tables have much overlap (sales and ar being the two with the most).  The reason I was trying to combine the tables was because I'm building a record management page and wanted to print out all of the results for a given query in one go, and I didn't understand why the query results were odd.

Comment: Looks like this kind of setup could work though.  Marking this as the answer for now and will return to update things once I get a chance to try and implement it.  For now, I'm just keeping all queries to a given subset table.  Thanks for the help.